# how to convert string to const char

Tags: c++, visual-c++

so i got that first problem working. i run the code and i am prompt to enter some list into the array. after entering the list i run this function as a search_func. but it keeps return no record found. is it because of [0], odd because i have it within a for loop.

Please help. `book books[]` is a class object..

```
int search(book books[], char search) {
    const char* boook =books[0].gettitle();
  //......try this but it failed please help
  cout << "Search books by title:____  ";

  cin >> search;

  bool yes = false;
  int size=2;

  for(int index=0; index<size; index++) {
    if(strcmp(boook,search) == 0 )//....error at this line
         { 
        found = true;
        cout<<"book found "<<endl;
        //cout<<"Author Name: "<<fn<<" "<<ln<<endl;
        break;
      }
  }

  if(!yes)
    cout<<"no book found"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Try books[0].gettitle().c_str(); ?

Comment: You're mixing C and C++. Either use arrays and C functions, or vectors and `std::string`. `std::string` works with `==`; no need for antiquated `strcmp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
const char* c_str = books[0].gettitle().c_str();
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

EDIT:

If `gettitle()` returns a temporary, then the above method won't work. You will need to do this instead:

```
string title = books[0].gettitle();
const char* c_str = title.c_str();
```

Comment: u dont know if gettitle() returns a temporal string object, if that's the case, this code will yield undefined behaviour when trying to use `c_str`

Comment: thanks that took care of that part. didnt know i needed to put .c_str() at the end

Comment: @smerlin: Yes, that is a possibility. I'll fix my answer to address that.

Comment: The reason is this: If a temporary is returned. It is destroyed after the statement ends. At which the pointer returned by `c_str()` is no longer valid. I have updated my answer to address this issue.

Comment: you can either store the `std::string` returned by gettitle() in a named std::string variable, or pass the `const char*` returned by c_str() directly to `strcmp`. If gettitle() returns a `std::string&` or a `const std::string&`, the old code was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the first argument is a std::string.  Try calling it's c_str() method.

Comment: search is a char (its in the question, but not correctly formatted in the code block)

Comment: @smerlin: It should be a `char*`, pointing to an array. Or, better, a `std::string`.